# Unary operator ++ cannot be applied to an operand of type Int

Tags: swift, int, unary-operator

Why does the following swift code bring me the error "Unary operator '++' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'Int'" ???  (using swift-1.2 on Xcode-6.3.2)

```
struct Set {

    var player1Games: Int
    var player2Games: Int

    init() {
        self.player1Games = 0
        self.player2Games = 0
    }

    func increasePlayer1GameScore () {
        player1Games++   // error: Unary operator '++' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'Int'
    }

    func increasePlayer2GameScore () {
        player2Games++   // error: Unary operator '++' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'Int'
    }

}
```

Comment: Set is a inbuilt type in swift. try renaming your struct. it should work

Answer (score 10):

The error message is a bit misleading. What you need to do is **add `mutating` before `func` to specify that it will [modify](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-ID241) the struct:**

```
struct MySet {

    var player1Games: Int
    var player2Games: Int

    init() {
        self.player1Games = 0
        self.player2Games = 0
    }

    mutating func increasePlayer1GameScore() {
        player1Games++
    }

    mutating func increasePlayer2GameScore() {
        player2Games++
    }

}
```

*Note: `Set` is a type in Swift, I would suggest to use a different name for your struct.*

Answer (score 5):

Use the `mutating` keyword before a function declaration to indicate you're mutating the class variables.

**OR**

Change your struct to a `class`.

This should fix your issues :).

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3 and later, the reason for this error is that the `++` and `--` operators have been removed from the language. It's recommended to use `x += 1` instead.

See [this very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35158570/3034366) for more detail on why this has happened.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Anyone who finds this page through a search for that error message will probably find this is the reason for the error (it was for me).

Comment: This was my problem, not sure why you were downvoted.