# Swift dictionary member compile error

Tags: swift

When I make a dictionary a member, assignment doesn't compile:

```
struct MyClass {
var lists = [String:Int]();
init() {}

func add() {

    // this compiles
    var x = [String:Int]();
    x["y"] = 3;

    // this gets the compiler error 'cannot assign to the result of this expression'
    self.lists["y"] = 3;
}
```

What is it about membership that breaks the compilation? I don't get this error if I put that line in init() FWIW.

Comment: If you want your struct to be able to modify its `self` you have to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30477167/2227743

Comment: You are right. I added "mutating" before "func add" and that fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `mutating` from the function declaration like this because properties are readonly if you don't specify that keyword in `struct`:

```
mutating func add()
```