# How write for(i=2;i<=num/2;i++){} in swift3

Tags: swift3

```
for(i=2;i<=num/2;i++){
```

}

How to write this loop in swift3 without using while loop and repeat while loop?

I want to use only for loop for this.But right now Swift3 remove the old c styling loop.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The ++ and -- operators have been deprecated Xcode 7.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158422/the-and-operators-have-been-deprecated-xcode-7-3)

Comment: My question is  not duplicate.In your link they are using half (..<) and full (…) ranges .They cannot be fit into my requirement. @Pragnesh solved my problem. Thanks for your reply

Comment: The `stride` solution is also mentioned in the linked topic.

Comment: Yes @Vadian ... My mistake . I missed that part. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write this:

```
for i in stride(from: 2, through: num/2, by: 1)
    {
        print(i)
    }
```