# Increment operator in inline conditional in Swift 3.1

Tags: swift3

```
column = column >= (numberOfColumns - 1) ? 0 : ++column
```

I am trying to increment my column variable through a `++` sign but it's now deprecated. What is the perfect sign for this increment?

I have tried both `column++` and `column += 1`. Though it works under a normal if-else condition, I want to implement this through an inline condition.

Comment: Related, and one of the answer probably addresses this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35158422/1531971

Comment: Your code would be much clearer if you simply used `column = (column + 1) % numberOfColumns`. It's easier to write and the intent is clearer to most programmers.

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple incrementation?

```
column = column >= (numberOfColumns - 1) ? 0 : column + 1
```